# Retrieve object from Mono in Java

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux

I have a SpringBoot app which is calling a WebClient to return a Mono . I am trying to retrieve the object from that Mono. I did the code below and looked up other similar questions here but couldn't get the solution.
The below code is getting a ClassCastException **class reactor.core.publisher.LambdaMonoSubscriber cannot be cast to class com.example.SpringBootReactiveClient.entity.Employee** when trying to cast the Disposable object to Employee.

Please could someone suggest a way I can get the Employee object.

```
Controller
----------------

 //http://localhost:8383/rxc/v1/getEmployeeByIdAsyncAndExecute/11351
    @GetMapping(value = "/getEmployeeByIdAsyncAndExecute/{id}", produces = "application/json")
    public Employee getEmployeeByIdAsyncAndExecute(@PathVariable("id") Integer id) {
        Mono<Employee> employeeMono = springBootReactiveClientService.getEmployeeByIdAsync(id);
        return (Employee) employeeMono.flatMap(this::updateEmployee).subscribe();
    }

    private Mono<Employee> updateEmployee(Employee employee) {
        employee.setEmail("firtName1.lastName1@gmail.com");
        return Mono.just(employee);
    }

Service
----------------

 public Mono<Employee> getEmployeeByIdAsync(Integer id) {
        return webClient
                .method(HttpMethod.GET)
                .uri("http://localhost:9898/rx/getEmployeeById/" + id)
                .accept(MediaType.ALL)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(Employee.class);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

The **ClassCastException** you're encountering is because you're trying to cast a Mono to an Employee directly, which is not how you should handle the result of a reactive operation. In your controller, you should use the reactive constructs provided by Project Reactor to process the data correctly. To get the Employee object, you should subscribe to the Mono and then return the result as a response. Here's the corrected code:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/getEmployeeByIdAsyncAndExecute/{id}", produces = "application/json")
public Mono<Employee> getEmployeeByIdAsyncAndExecute(@PathVariable("id") Integer id) {
    return springBootReactiveClientService.getEmployeeByIdAsync(id)
            .flatMap(this::updateEmployee);
}

private Mono<Employee> updateEmployee(Employee employee) {
    employee.setEmail("firtName1.lastName1@gmail.com");
    return Mono.just(employee);
}
```

Additionally, make sure that you handle the Mono and Flux types correctly throughout your application to leverage the benefits of reactive programming. Your service and data layer should also return reactive types when working with external services or databases.

Comment: +1 for that...Thanks! I have a follow-up question... this is still returning a Mono<Employee> ..how to make this method return just Employee? Or am I missing something here? Please suggest..

Comment: I have updated my answer hopefully it will help you